# Notice: Undefined variable: Lastname in C:\wamp\www\COP3718\tt2^homas12\delete.php on line 15

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a database and within the tables I have two options, insert and delete.  I have the insert option working but can not get the delete function working for me.  (I need to insert an update option once I have this working)  I am including my code and am hopeful someone will see my error on this, I have been working on getting this project done for two weeks now.  Thank You in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h1>Franchise Call Log</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","tt2^homas12","c3o7P1518","tt2^homas12");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM caller_info");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Franchise</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Franchise'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html> 

<h1>Insert a New Caller</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Franchise: <input type="text" name="franchise">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Delete a Caller</h1>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Record has been updated</h1>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","tt2^homas12","c3o7P1518","tt2^homas12");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= ("DELETE FROM caller_info WHERE Lastname = '$Lastname'");

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record deleted";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The $Lastname variable is never set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On delete.php you are not getting the data from `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
$Lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

}else{
echo "Error";die();
}
$sql= ("DELETE FROM caller_info WHERE Lastname = '$Lastname'");
```

---

> Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)  and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi with bind params](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).